# What does the * mean in "res://*/"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I see something  like

`res://*/Some.Name.Space.csdl|res://*/Some.Name.Space.ssdl|res://*/Some.Name.Space.msl`

in an Entity Framework connection string, what does the `*` mean in `res://*/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a wildcard for the assemblyFullName part of an embedded resource:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx

> If you specify a wildcard (*) for assemblyFullName, the Entity
> Framework runtime will search for resources in the following
> locations, in this order:
> The calling assembly.
>
> The referenced assemblies.
>
> The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.
>
> If the files are not in one of these locations, an exception will be
> thrown.
>
> Note: When you use wildcard (*), the Entity Framework has to
> look through all the assemblies for resources with the correct name.
> To improve performance, specify the assembly name instead of the
> wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

see [Entity Framework Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx)

If you specify a wildcard (*) for assemblyFullName, the Entity Framework runtime will search for resources in the following locations, in this order:

1. The calling assembly.
2. The referenced assemblies.
3. The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.